# Ngrx store: Execute select handler on a specific slice change with extra data

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have a store state as:

```
export interface DocumentState {
  document: Document;
  selectedPage: number;
}
```

I want to call `DoSomethingOnlyOnDocumentChange(doc: Document)` and `DoSomethingOnlyOnPageChange(Document: doc, page: number)`. The idea is not to execute the handlers on other's state change. I have subscribed to state changes as follows:

```
this.store$.select(appState => appState.documentState.document).subscribe(this.DoSomethingOnlyOnDocumentChange);
this.store$.select(appState => appState.documentState.selectedPage).subscribe(this.DoSomethingOnlyOnPageChange);
```

How do I access the document in page change state handler?

Answer (score 0):

That's the reason why `ngrx selectors` exist.

First create a selector for the state slice you need:

```
export const selectDocument = createFeatureSelector<AppState, 
  DocumentState>('document');

export const getDocument = createSelector(
  selectDocument,
  (state: DocumentState) => state.document
);
```

Then use it in your component:

```
this.store$.select(getDocument).subscribe(this.DoSomethingOnlyOnDocumentChange);
```

This way only changes made to the document slice will be handled by `DoSomethingOnlyOnDocumentChange`

Ref: [ngrx documentation](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors)